# getJSON function always returns null

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, getjson

I am trying to make a get http request using jquery getJSON function. I have implemented it like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#query").keyup(function(event) {
        keyword = $("#query").val();
        $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?", showdata );
    });
});
function showdata(data, status) {
    alert(data + ":" + status);
}
</script>
```

This always returns null. I have checked the HTTP Headers, they are null as well. But if I directly use the URL, it displays JSON in the browser window.

What am I doing wrong?

Some suggested I should use JSONP, but in the URL I will actually using, there is some sensitive information which I don't want to reveal, so I want to stick with getJSON.

Regards

Comment: actually your codes is somewhat just similar to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON/ example ... I was wondering if you are doing any other thing...

Comment: @Reigel - the only other thing I am doing different is using a different URL. I tried the one given in getJSON, that too returned null so I though there is some problem.

Comment: is your link/url on same domain?

Comment: @Reigel - no its not on the same domain.

Comment: well, read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: You're already using JSONP :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Reigel - no its not on the same domain.

your problem is because of the [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: So does this mean that I have to use JSONP? Also why was the flicker api working over here - api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON and not my api?

Comment: would you mind to explain why http://www.jsfiddle.net/htcxT/1/ works ? It's the exact same code from OP

Comment: @jAndy - both works. the only thing is, the OP's url was just an example... The OP's real url is not in the same domain and not using JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

As @Reigel suggested the problem was of same-origin-policy, so I have decided to create a proxy by using a server-based code which returns the correct json.